# AJAX username Availability

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have writtin this code to check the email availability.

```
var email = $('#email_reg').val();
       if(email && email.length > 0)
       {
         if(!isValidEmailAddress(email))
         {
           isValid = false;
           $('#msg_email').html('Email is invalid').show();           
         }
         else
         {jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'check_username.php',
            data: 'email='+ email ,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 1){
                    $('#msg_email').html('Email already Exists').show();
                    isValid=false;
                }
                else {
                    $('#msg_email').html('').hide();
                }
            }
        });

         }
       }
       else
       {
         isValid = false;
         $('#msg_email').html('Please enter email').show();
       }
```

**The php Code is**

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/connection.php');
$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["email"]);

if (!$con)
{
    echo 0;
}
else {
    mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vendor_logiin WHERE username='" . $username . "'");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num; //it will always return 1 or 0 since we do not allow multiple users with the same user name.
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Now all the others work well like when left it empty and give a wrong email format.But the problem is when i give an email Id that already exists. It didnot give error.
I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: What response do you get from the server? Do a `console.log(response)` in the AJAX success callback.

Comment: `vendor_logiin` is it with 2x " i "?

Comment: Is tis table name correct: `vendor_logiin`. If not the query will fail and whatever you get back from the server, it's not likely to be 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify `dataType` the response is probably treated as text or html and in that case it might be wise to do the comparison as a string:

```
if (response == "1") {...}
```

instead of a number. Or use `parseInt(response, 10) == 1` if you compare it as a number.

Comment: i guess the problem is in jquery code. because in all conditions it dnt give error.