# How to make a real time validation form with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I was looking around for ways to make it but I only seen it being done with ajax and no PHP explanation/usage at all.

What do I mean?: I want the username check validation to be done at real time, means that if the user inserts a username that already exists, it will immediately show an error message.

Example of what I mean:

register.php

```
if(isset($_POST["reg"]))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='$name');
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query))
    {
        ... 
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

form.html

```
    <head>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#error").hide();
         });
        </script>
    </head>

    <div id="error">
        Username exists.
    </div>

    <form action="register.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="reg" />
    </form>
```

(Only the relevant code has been copied for comfort, the other required tags exist in the original code)

I want the #error div to show whenever the username exists (without reloading the page) and to hide whenever everything is okay, and disallow the user to submit the form, I'm not sure how can I  do it efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need some Ajax code, with your PHP echo'ing back a response. An example here on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258541/ajax-username-availability

Comment: Can you please explain it to me how it works? I see the code, but an explanation would be nice :)

Comment: Search for tutorials on ajax

Comment: [jQuery AJAX Basics](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You use `$.ajax()` to send the value of `<input name="name">` to `register.php`. In `register.php` you check that value and then echo a response if it is available or unavailable. And in the `success: function(response){ }` of your `$.ajax()`you do something with that response, i.e. show your error message or post the form to insert that value.